# Issue with configuring logging on the Content Manager server

Tags: logging, monitoring

I am facing some fundamental issue with configuring logging on the Content Manager server. SDL-2011 SP1

Issue:

When i put the log.level="WARN" its creating the log files but with  no data into it 
Its working fine it i change the log.level="ALL" or "INFO". I cant make it "ALL" or "INFO" on production environment :(

What i tried till now:

I have configure the logging and set the level to "WARN", in CMS i have stopped the Transport service so when i am publishing something i am expected some error logs to be generated in  transport.log file but not the case its showing a 0KB file.

Hope i am able to explain my problem :)
Looking forward for some expert touch :)

Comment: hi all still haven't got any solution - So let me explain the issue here                   When i put the log.level="WARN" its creating the log files but with no data it creates a 0 Kb file but if i change the log.level="ALL" or "INFO" its work fine . I cant make it "ALL" or "INFO" on production environment :(

Answer (score 2):

The transport log logs events that occur *during* transportation *by the transport service itself*. By having the transport service stopped, there is simply nothing running to update the log. Your transport packages will probably just wait to be picked up when a transport service comes back up again or may fail with a timeout after a while.

If you're trying to detect the unavailability of a service, I suggest that you look into the Tridion monitoring service, which will watch other Tridion services for you and raise SNMP notifications etc. See [Monitoring SDL Tridion Processes](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-FECAF9CC-564F-4999-B50B-42D9AB776727) in the online documentation for more information.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your reply, yes I am exactly looking to detect the unavailability of a service, and for that I am trying to implement Tridion monitoring service.  Please correct me if I am wrong here logback.xml is directly related to cd_monitor_conf.xml? So in cd_monitor_conf.xml we define which service needs to be monitored and in logback.xml we defined which information needs to be recorded (please correct me if I am wrong here) so the problem here is if I set log.level=“WARN” it logs info in  “cd_monitoring.log “ but if I set the Log.Level=”INFO” it starts generating info.